# name and place each element of a list in Global Environment

Tags: r

If you have a `list` but you want each element of the list to be it's own separate element in the global environment e.g.

```
alist <- list( c(1,2), c(3,4) )
# into
a <- c(1,2)
b <- c(3,4)
```

Is there an easy way to this? something of the form below perhaps:

```
mapply(function(x,y){ y <- x }, alist, list("a","b"), SIMPLIFY = FALSE )
```

Comment: You want `assign` rather than `<-`.

Comment: And you really shouldn't want to do this.

Comment: thanks for the answers, @Roland is it just because best practice means I should continue to work within the list format or is there another reason?

Comment: @user1320502 I guess the question is why do you want them as objects in the global environment? Typically beginners want to do this to reference something later but that can just as easily be done with the elements in the list using `[[` indexing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `list2env`

```
alist <- list( a=c(1,2), b=c(3,4) )  # naming list elements
list2env(alist, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your elements aren't named, then you can do `mapply` with assign:

```
mapply(assign, list("a","b"), alist, MoreArgs=list(envir=.GlobalEnv))
> ls()
## [1] "a"     "alist" "b"
```

But what Roland said.