# applying function to set of objects referred to by name

Tags: r

I have defined 8 matrices `A1`, `A2`, ..., `A8`. Now I want to give all of them the same rownames (some character vector `rnames') but I am too lazy to type:

```
rownames(A1) <- rnames
rownames(A2) <- rnames
rownames(A3) <- rnames
rownames(A4) <- rnames
rownames(A5) <- rnames
rownames(A6) <- rnames
rownames(A7) <- rnames
rownames(A8) <- rnames
```

(Yes, yes I just typed it, but less gloss over that for now.)

Instead, I want to have a function to do this for me. I thought the following would work:

```
matrices <- paste(A, seq(1, 8), sep = "")
for(m in matrices){
    rownames(eval(as.name(m))) <- rnames
}
```

But somehow R gets confused about where I put my parentheses and insists that I asked him to use the function `"eval<-"` rather than `"rownames<-"`. What is going on here and how can I remedy it?

Comment: it's generally more convenient to put similar objects into a list

Comment: @Cath Thank you for finding this other question! I agree that putting the matrices in a list would have been more convenient and it is really helpful to learn from the other question how to do it after the fact (using `mget`). However, out of curiosity: when the matrices are in a list it is easy to give all of them the right rownames, but is there then a way to get them out of the list into the global environment again?

Comment: Yes I don't know why either, but I still want to know how in order to understand R better. So how would I do that?

Comment: There is a function `list2env` to do that, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/20657609/4137985